# Edit menu permission issue

Tags: menu, alacarte, menulibre

i'm an Lubuntu user, but i suppose it concerns everyone.

For menu editing there are 3 GUIs: `lxmed`, `menulibre`, `alacarte`. great!
Still the ISSUE is that if i start as administrator, for example:

`gram@gram-pc:~$ alacarte` will edit menu, till the time i close app. it doesn't have permission for that...
so nothing in menu has been changed...

`gram@gram-pc:~$ gksudo alacarte` or `root@gram-pc:/# alacarte` will open completely different menu with completely different items...

how can i grand permission to edit my-not-root-menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround. Not the actual solution for your problem:

Execute this command in Terminal:

> sudo chmod 777 /usr/share/applications/*

We permitted the entire world to change  your menu settings.
 So alacarte can save settings as well.

To revert this execute command:

> sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/applications/*

Comment: Glad I could help! :)